# Editing bounties would be nice, can that be added?

Tags: feature-request

I just made a bounty and didnt specify a distance of 4000' as being elevation...now its an excuse for a lazy answer. Simple edit to the comment in the bounty would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like editing bounties and the messages would be a meta item, as that is a system feature not a site feature.

You could add your support to [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/can-we-have-a-way-to-edit-bounty-custom-message), as it looks like it's been requested and highly upvoted for a couple years.